# trace a nested recursion in Ocaml

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to understand deeply nested recursion in OCaml by using the sorting list algorithm. For this reason I am tracing the below code which has a recursive function `sort` and calls another function `insert`.

```ml
let rec sort (lst : int list) =
  match lst with [] -> [] | head :: tail -> insert head (sort tail)

and insert elt lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> [ elt ]
  | head :: tail -> if elt <= head then elt :: lst else head :: insert elt tail
```

I understand the first recursive calls for `sort`, but after that I cannot follow.

For instance, suppose we have the list `[6, 2, 5, 3]`. After sorting the `tail` of this list as `2,3,5` where in the code the `head` `6` is compared to each element of this tail?  Can somebody provide a hint for the trace results?

```
utop # sort [6; 2; 5; 3];;        
> sort <-- [6; 2; 5; 3]                                                 
> sort <-- [2; 5; 3]                                                    
> sort <-- [5; 3]                                                       
> sort <-- [3]                                                          
> sort <-- []                                                           
> sort --> []                                                           
> insert <-- 3                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- []                                                        
> insert* --> [3]                                                       
> sort --> [3]                                                          
> insert <-- 5                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- [3]                                                       
> insert <-- 5                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- []                                                        
> insert* --> [5]                                                       
> insert* --> [3; 5]                                                    
> sort --> [3; 5]                                                       
> insert <-- 2                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- [3; 5]                                                    
> insert* --> [2; 3; 5]                                                 
> sort --> [2; 3; 5]                                                    
> insert <-- 6                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- [2; 3; 5]                                                 
> insert <-- 6                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- [3; 5]                                                    
> insert <-- 6                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- [5]                                                       
> insert <-- 6                                                          
> insert -->                                                            
> insert* <-- []                                                        
> insert* --> [6]                                                       
> insert* --> [5; 6]                                                    
> insert* --> [3; 5; 6]                                                 
> insert* --> [2; 3; 5; 6]                                              
> sort --> [2; 3; 5; 6]                                                 
> 
> - : int list = [2; 3; 5; 6]**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no reason to have `insert` and `sort` being mutually recursive since `insert` doesn't depend on `sort`. So you could write it like this:

```ml
let rec insert elt lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> [ elt ]
  | head :: tail -> if elt <= head then elt :: lst else head :: insert elt tail

let rec sort (lst : int list) =
  match lst with [] -> [] | head :: tail -> insert head (sort tail)
```

Now, what happens in `insert`? The function tries to insert an element `elt` in a **sorted** list with the invariant that all elements before it should be smaller and all the elements after should be higher.

Two cases happen:

- if the list is empty, the invariant in ensure if you just return a list containing the element you were trying to insert.
- if the list is not, it's composed of an element we'll call `head` and the rest of the list that we'll call `tail`. Now we have two new cases:

  - if `elt <= head` then all the elements of the list are higher than `elt` so you just return `elt :: list` (for example if you call `insert 1 [2; 3; 4]` you'll return `[1; 2; 3; 4]`
  - otherwise, `head < elt` so we need to add `head` in front of the list that will be returned by inserting `elt` to `tail`, hence the recursive call to `insert elt tail`

Now, when you call sort you call it like this:

```ml
insert head (sort tail)
```

Why so? Because the invariant only works if the list you're trying to insert head into is sorted (hence the bold sorted before). So you need to sort `tail` before inserting `head` into it.

If you have the following list: `[3; 2; 1]`, you'll call

`insert 3 (sort [2; 1])`

which is transformed in

`insert 3 (insert 2 (sort [1]))`

which is transformed in

`insert 3 (insert 2 (insert 1 (sort [])))`

which is resolved in

`insert 3 (insert 2 [1])`

which is resolved in

`insert 3 [1; 2]`

which is resolved in

`[1; 2; 3]`

And your list is sorted.

---

[EDIT]

Here's the code with some printing to see what's happening:

```ml
let pp_sep ppf () = Format.fprintf ppf "; "

let rec insert elt lst =
  Format.printf "@[<v 2>(Insert %d in [%a]" elt
    Format.(pp_print_list ~pp_sep (fun ppf d -> fprintf ppf "%d" d))
    lst;
  let l =
    match lst with
    | [] -> [ elt ]
    | head :: tail ->
        if elt <= head then elt :: lst
        else (
          Format.printf "@,";
          head :: insert elt tail)
  in
  Format.printf ")@]";
  l

let rec sort (lst : int list) =
  match lst with
  | [] -> []
  | head :: tail ->
      Format.printf "@[<v 2>(Sort [%a] then insert %d@,"
        Format.(pp_print_list ~pp_sep (fun ppf d -> fprintf ppf "%d" d))
        tail head;
      let l = insert head (sort tail) in
      Format.printf ")@]@,";
      l
```

```
# sort [3;2;1];;
(Sort [2; 1] then insert 3
  (Sort [1] then insert 2
    (Sort [] then insert 1
      (Insert 1 in []))
    (Insert 2 in [1]
      (Insert 2 in [])))
  (Insert 3 in [1; 2]
    (Insert 3 in [2]
      (Insert 3 in []))))
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

Comment: Let's take the last insert  `insert 3 [1; 2] `. Here, head=2 and elt=3. So, elt>head and insert will be call another two times until finally resolved at the end of the list (1,2).

Comment: No, head = 1 but the rest of the reasoning is correct. And yes, insert will be called with `3` and `[2]` then `3` and `[]` and resolved in `[1; 2; 3]`

Comment: @tkyo I edited my answer to show what happens step by step

Answer (score 0):

In a sort by insertion, it is the insertion function that performs the comparisons between the element to be inserted and the currently sorted list.
You can see that your trace inserts the elements of your list in reverse order:

```
 insert <-- 3                                                          
 ...
 insert <-- 5
 ...
 insert <-- 5
 ...
 insert <-- 2                                                           
 ...                                                          
 insert <-- 6                                                          
 ...
 insert <-- 6                                                          
 ...
 insert <-- 6                                                          
 ...
 insert <-- 6                                                          
 ...
```

A possible next step is to figure why `insert` is called four times with `6` as an argument and only once with `2` as an argument.